# C wrapper for a C++ class not working

Tags: c++, api, class, wrapper

I've a C++ library which exposes some APIs (thru cppH.h) & it's a static library (*.lib).
I want to use this in a C code hence wrote a C Wrapper as below.  However, I'm getting build errors as below. Kindly help me in this regard to know what am i missing. I refered from [here](https://www.teddy.ch/c++_library_in_c/)

**cppH.h - Header file of the C++ Library**

```
class Abc
{
    int ma, mb;
public:
    void pass(int a,int b);
    int  sum();
};
```

**CWrapper.h**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    typedef struct Abc_C Abc_C;
    Abc_C* New_Abc();
    void pass_in_C(Abc_C* cobj, int a, int b);
    int  sum_in_C(Abc_C* cobj);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**CWrapper.cpp**

```
#include "CWrapper.h"
#include "cppH.h"  
extern "C" {
    Abc_C* New_Abc()
    {
        return new Abc_C();
    }

    void pass_in_C(Abc_C* cobj, int a, int b)
    {
        cobj->pass(a, b);
    }

    int  sum_in_C(Abc_C* cobj)
    {
        cobj->sum();
    }

}
```

> CWrapper.cpp & CWrapper.h statically links to the C++ library cppH.lib
>   & cppH.h.

**Compilation error**:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: CApp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  CS.c
1>  CWarpperS.cpp
1>c:\users\user1\documents\ccg\vsprojects\expapp\capp\cwarppers.cpp(7): error C2512: 'Abc_C' : no appropriate default constructor available
1>c:\users\user1\documents\ccg\vsprojects\expapp\capp\cwarppers.cpp(12): error C2027: use of undefined type 'Abc_C'
1>          c:\users\user1\documents\ccg\vsprojects\expapp\capp\cwrapper.h(6) : see declaration of 'Abc_C'
1>c:\users\user1\documents\ccg\vsprojects\expapp\capp\cwarppers.cpp(12): error C2227: left of '->pass' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>c:\users\user1\documents\ccg\vsprojects\expapp\capp\cwarppers.cpp(17): error C2027: use of undefined type 'Abc_C'
1>          c:\users\user1\documents\ccg\vsprojects\expapp\capp\cwrapper.h(6) : see declaration of 'Abc_C'
1>c:\users\user1\documents\ccg\vsprojects\expapp\capp\cwarppers.cpp(17): error C2227: left of '->sum' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: What is `cwarppers.cpp` in the compiler error log? You've shown no such file (albeit it seems to be spelled wrong).

Comment: `extern "C"` does not mean it is C code, just that it uses the C ABI and naming conventions. The function body is still C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types `class Abc` and `struct Abc_C` (which is defined nowhere) are completely unrelated. Your typedef in the C header is wrong. It's an alias for a type that isn't defined. Therefore `new Abc_C();` is attempting to create an object of an incomplete type.

An easy fix is to change the alias as follows:

```
typedef struct Abc Abc_C;
```

Now the alias is a name for the correct type.